# Generic algorithm for element wise operation between hundreds of lists

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

I have been tasked to write an algorithm for a project. Basically, i scan the data to get the unique items and store their positions in an array. So i end up with multiple arrays with variable length. Now i have to do element wise operations on ALL of these arrays and their elements. Note that these will always be sorted (if that matters)

```
a = [0, 7, 13, 18]
b = [1, 2, 8, 10]
c = [0, 3, 5, 6, 7]
```

The current solution i have is a pretty basic loop solution where i loop through every array and compare its element with every other array and its elements. It works for small number of arrays and, as you can imagine, doesn't work well where i have a lot of unique items each with their own array/list.

```
def add(a, b):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(len(b)):
            result.append(a[i] + b[j])
    return result


a = [0, 7, 13, 18]
b = [1, 2, 8, 10]
c = [0, 3, 5, 6, 7]
total_unique_items = [a, b, c]
calc = []


for i in range(len(total_unique_items)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(total_unique_items)):
        calc.append(add(total_unique_items[i], total_unique_items[j]))
    print(calc)
```

I know there are pythonic solutions like zip but my teacher is asking for a generic language-independent solution here.

I am not really sure how to tackle this problem. One way would be to use a data structure like a tree or a graph and traverse through it? the other way would be to find a way to perform the operation on all the array's ith elements in ith iteration of the loop. This way, my main loop would run for the length of the longest array. I am just really confused about it and would love to get an idea of the direction i should go from here.

Comment: total_unique_items is a list of the lists. i made those a, b, c lists just for the purpose of demonstration. or did you mean something else?

Comment: are you able to use any libraries written for python? it seems like itertools is what you need here

Comment: @emilaz yes, and i can do it with zip too. But my teacher is asking for a generic solution without using any libraries.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what is the problem you have to tackle... Is your code working as expected ? If yes, are you asking for a neater solution ? Otherwise, what is the expected output ?

Comment: @Nei Yes, my code is working and the output is correct. But if i have multiple arrays, say 1000 (instead of just a, b, c) it takes hours. Basically, this solution doesn't scale very well. I am asking for how i can optimize this to work on a bigger scale.

Comment: What element-wise operations do you need to do?

Comment: @kaya3 multiply.

Comment: What does that mean? Do you want a new list containing the products of each "row", or a new list containing the products of each "column", or just the product of all the numbers in all lists? Please give an example of input and expected output.

Comment: @kaya3 Yes, i want the product of all numbers in all lists. So if i have a[0, 1, 2] and b[1, 3, 5] then i would want result[ (0x1), (0x3), (0x5), (1x1), (1x3), (1x5), (2x1), (2x3), (2x5)]. The problem isn't that i can't get this output, the problem is that it takes a lot of time if i have multiple arrays. I am trying to find a way to do it on a bigger scale because the current solutions takes hours if i have 1000 arrays with 100,000 values.

Comment: Your program is slow because the output is large. Anything which produces an output with that many numbers will be that slow. If you have two arrays of length 100,000 each and you want a list of all pairs multiplied together, then your output will have 100,000 * 100,000 = 10,000,000,000 elements. Imagine if you had 1000 lists of that length... I think you might have misunderstood what you have been asked to do.

Comment: @depressedminkycoder That means that as the output is of length `n²` for `n` being the length of lists, it would lead to a minimal complexity of your algorithm of `O(n²)`, which means that when you double the length of the lists, you approx. quadruple the time of execution, and so if you multiply by 10 the lengths, you multiply by 100 the execution time, and so on...

Comment: And if you increase the number of lists instead, the output is of length `(n-1)*n / 2` with `n` being the number of lists. As I understood, this is actually what you have to do. And so the complexity is of `O(n(n-1)) = O(n²)`, so you have the same problem. So it seems like there is not much we can do to optimize the algorithm